# jquery combine two mysql values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I use jquery (JQwidgets)to display values in a grid. I have a database with multiple columns and lets say i have in column A the value "http://www.google.com" and in column B the value "Google".

What i want is to display "Google" in the grid and when people click on it it opens the url.

Right now i have this code wich gets the variables from the database.

```
        var source =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
            { name: 'sitename', type: 'string'},
    { name: 'url', type: 'string'},
            ],
            url: 'http://www.site.com/data.php',  
            cache: false
        };
```

After that the values are displayed using this...

```
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            pagesize : 25,
            pagesizeoptions: ['25', '50', '100'],
            width : 1170,
            theme:"black",
            source: dataAdapter,
            pageable: true, 
            autoheight: true,
            selectionmode: 'multiplecellsextended',
            columns: [
            { text: 'Website', datafield: 'website' , width: 700, cellsrenderer: linkrenderer},
            ]
        });
```

So what i cannot get to work is to combine the two values. What i tried is this...

```
        var website = function (row, datafield, value) {
            return 'sitename' + 'url';
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set a linkrenderer function.

Above it, add

```
var linkrenderer = function(row, column, value, defaultHtml, columnSettings, rowData) {
   return '<a href="' + rowData.url + '">' + value + '</div>';
}
```

The last column rowData is a JSON object of everything already rendered, so maybe add the columns

```
columns: [{text: 'URL', datafield: 'url' , width: 100}, {text: 'Website', datafield: 'sitename' , width: 700, cellsrenderer: linkrenderer}]
```

Hiding the URL column

```
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('hidecolumn', 'url');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this is the linkrenderer i have... -    var linkrenderer = function (row, column, value) {
                if (value.indexOf('#') != -1) {
                    value = value.substring(0, value.indexOf('#'));
                }
                var format = { target: '"_blank" data-rokbox=""' };
                var html = $.jqx.dataFormat.formatlink(value, format);
                return html;
            }

Comment: It just didn't look like you were using the 'website' column because it isn't in your dataFields within your data source. But if you are, then just create the separate columns (url, and sitename) and use the cellsrenderer function I provided.